# Plupload (1.5.4) not working on Chrome24 when the runtime is HTML5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, plupload

`Plupload (1.5.4)` not working on `Chrome24` when the run-time is `HTML5`???

It was working with all versions of chrome less than 24

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#html5_uploader").pluploadQueue({
runtimes: 'html5',
url: '/Plupload.ashx',
max_file_size: '500mb',
chunk_size: '1mb',
unique_names: true,
filters: [{ title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png,tif,tiff,jpeg"}]
});
</script>
<form>
<h4>HTML 5 runtime</h4>
<div id="html5_uploader">You browser doesn't support native upload. Try Firefox 3 or Safari 4.</div>
</form>
```

above code uploads images with size less than chunk_size, but if the image size is more than chunk_size then not uploading.

Comment: do you have the queue script in your header and the full?, check with flash the same problem

Comment: @RicardoVieira: I have the queue script and the full. With Flash its working. Only with Html5 it does not work.